# Eval piece of code stored in DB as string

Tags: php, go

I'm moving part of my application from PHP to Go. I'm storing some pieces of code to eval in MySQL, for example: `checkGeo('{geo:["DE","AU","NL"]}') && check0s('{os:["android"]}')`. In PHP it is easy, just `eval($stringToEval)`, but how can this be done in Go lang?

Comment: It's considered bad practise even in PHP, and really isn't a good approach in any programming language

Comment: @MarkBaker, yes, I know that eval is a bad practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In an interpreted language like PHP, implementing eval is fairly simple. But Go is a compiled language. To implement eval in Go would require writing an interpreter for Go. This would not be impossible, but it would be a big job.

-Edit
You can have a look at https://godoc.org/bitbucket.org/binet/go-eval/pkg/eval which might do what you want. If it doesn't you could then maybe expand on it a bit. It isn't a full interpreter though.

Comment: Exactly! That's why I'm asking. The best I can do is to parse this expression and invoke it part by part with `CallFunc`, imho. What do you think?

Comment: How is it possible to eval dynamic logical structures in Go?

Comment: Thank you for update. That is possibly what I am looking for. PS: I don't need full language support.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the examples you gave it seems like it'd be trivial-ish to build a bit of go code that knows how to evaluate checkGeo() or checkOs() rules; I think that'd be the best approach.

But that's not what you asked...

Another option would be to write the rules in Lua and run them with https://github.com/aarzilli/golua or in Javascript and use https://github.com/robertkrimen/otto

Comment: Thank you for your solution using `Lua` and `javascript`. Never thought about this approach.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pull in a full-blown interpreter for this sort of thing: write a simple parser that would pull your script apart into the syntax tree, and then write code that would walk that tree and "evaluate" it.  It's not really *that* hard for simplistic cases like yours.  And of course, your syntax might be made way simpler than PHP's since you don't want the full power of PHP's evaluator.

One simple example is [`rpn`](https://github.com/zephyrtronium/rpn), but you can go simpler and invent a way to store your queries in, say, JSON.

Also note that Go has a Go parser in the form of a Go package — [`go/parser`](http://golang.org/pkg/go/parser/) so you can write your queries using (minimal) Go syntax, parse them with `go/parser` and only implement an evaluator which would walk the AST produced by the parser and calculate the result.  But I think this would be an overengeneering, given the example you've provided.

And a minor nitpick: storing the code which is to be evaluated by a full-blown evaluator, like PHP, is dangerous: if someone somehow manages to inject a call to `exec()` or something like this in your table, the result will be suboptimal.  So having a primitive parser/evaluator is an upside from the security standpoint as well.

Comment: I really appreciate your full answer. Thank you very much for useful advises and techniques!